# Searching for a ruby on rails group gem with visability options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, permissions, rubygems

I am looking for a Rails Gem which gives only me the ability to add users to certain groups. Each User can get many groups.
And with these groups they get the ability to see posts assigned to their group. (for users i actually use devise)

So:

```
user1 has group with id 1
user2 has group with id 1 and 2
```

I have 3 posts:

```
post1 has group3
post2 has group2
post3 has group1

User1 can only see post3
User2 can only see post2 and post3
Non of them can see post1
```

It would be cool if you can help me with a gem or a tutorial. Or maybe a hint for searching on my own. I have no more idea how i can google this.

Comment: Take a look at [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Do you need something like [groupify[(https://github.com/dwbutler/groupify) or [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify)?